# how to check a word palindrome or not in python

Tags: python

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    n1 = word
    n2 = word[::-1]
    if n1 == n2 :
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

I tried this but getting error like Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "Code", line 3, in isPalindrome
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'.
```

How to handle numbers here?

Comment: It is perfectly correct code??? what kind of input are you giving?

Comment: n1 is word what we are going to give.Where word[::-1] will give reverse of n1.

Comment: Your code is correct. You might be messing up during function call. Can you provide us the function call code too?

Comment: Error message is `'int' object ...`. Do you have control over the input parameter? I would convert it to string by function str().

Comment: ya converted int to string using str().Working fine.

Comment: @VineetKumarDoshi I missed to conver that int to string.Because of that got error.Now it is working fine.Thank you brother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the word to string using `str()` before using them. Example -

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    n1 = str(word)
    n2 = str(word)[::-1]
    if n1 == n2 :
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

If `word` is int it would be converted to string. Otherwise , if its already stirng, it would remain string.

Answer (score 5):

```
def is_palindrome(s):
   s = str(s) 
   return s == s[::-1]
```

Very slightly nicer rewrite of Anands answer (imho).

Note: python function names should be lowercase_separated_by_underscores according to PEP 0008 unless that breaks local convention.  (For any dirty Java programmers out there https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names )

Answer (score 0):

It might be extended to test a sentence:

```
import re

def is_palindrome(sentence):
    sentence = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]','',str(sentence)).lower()
    return sentence == sentence[::-1]
```